# why error is displaying"'list' object has no attribute 'values'" while doing scaler.fit transform before train the model in LSTM using python

Tags: python, time, lstm

Here I have a dataset with four inputs. So here I want to predict the one output using LSTM model. so for y value I create the value using append value in every one hour.

```
 X = 1
 n_out = 1

 x,y=list(),list()
 start =0


for _ in range(len(df)):
in_end = start+X
out_end= in_end + n_out
if out_end < len(df):
    x_input = df[start:in_end]
    x.append(x_input)
    y.append(df[in_end:out_end,0])
start +=1
```

Here after the append value y value is displaying like this .

```
2018-06-08 06:15:00          141.0
2018-06-08 07:15:00          0
2018-06-08 08:15:00          0
2018-06-08 09:15:00          0
2018-06-08 10:15:00          0
2018-06-08 11:15:00          0
2018-06-08 12:15:00          0
2018-06-08 13:15:00          0
2018-06-08 14:15:00          0
2018-06-08 15:15:00          0
2018-06-08 16:15:00          0
2018-06-08 17:15:00          0
2018-06-08 18:15:00          0
2018-06-08 19:15:00          0
2018-06-08 20:15:00          0
2018-06-08 21:15:00          0
2018-06-08 22:15:00          0
```

After this I did scaler.fit transform for Y value. Then it gave me this error.

Here is my code:

```
y = y.values.astype(int)
scaler_y = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(0, 1))
y = np.array(y).reshape([-1, 1])
y = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)
```

error:

first error:

```html
ttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-240-6ac9211db656> in <module>()
----> 1 y = y.values.astype(int)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-ad4efba4dd31> in <module>()
      1 scaler_y = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(0, 1))
      2 y = np.array(y).reshape([-1, 1])
----> 3 y = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    515         if y is None:
    516             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 517             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    518         else:
    519             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    306         # Reset internal state before fitting
    307         self._reset()
--> 308         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    309 
    310     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    332 
    333         X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy, warn_on_dtype=True,
--> 334                         estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    335 
    336         data_min = np.min(X, axis=0)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: "{'level': [141.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Your `y` variable looks like a `Series`, try `y = y.values.astype(int)` in the first line instead of `y = np.array(y)`

Comment: @Sayandip Dutta thank you for the fast response. When I used it I got an error 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: Try printing `y.values` and see what you get, if you get something like `<built-in function>` then try printing `y.values()` if that shows an array do `y.values().astype(int)`. If even that doesn't work, please check the type of `y`.

Comment: @Sayandip Dutta I got this error .'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: what is the type of y?

Comment: @ Matias Valdenegro  y is the input value of X1 (one hour )  I uploaded the code for y value. You may can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer . Thank you for all the response.

my code is :

```
y = [int(x) for x in y]
```

Comment: @ Sayandip Dutta ,@Matias Valdenegro Here is my code. This code worked properly for me.